# joomla: multiple views with dynamic contents

Tags: php, joomla

I just recently got involved in a project which uses joomla to manage its homepage and started to learn the basics of joomla.

Until now I see that joomla is quite nice if you have pages with static content and you can manage them nicely. But what I want now is to add dynamic content to this pages (fetched from a database or some other backend). If I understand the principle right one would do that with modules or even components (I am not sure how plugins could help for such things). But do I need to create one module for each view with dynamic content?

What I would like to have is something like a service where I can implement the data fetching logic and then it should be possible to create the views with a WYSIWYG editor where I can insert with php the fetched values. I already know that one can use php in the WYSIWYG editor via the extension Sourcerer.

In the end I would like to have something like this in the WYSIWYG editor:

```
{source}
<?php
$data = service.fetchData(...); // fetches view specific data from a central service which gets the data from a backend or a database
?>
{/source}

...html code (in WYSIWYG style)
<p>Hello {source}<?= $data['name']?> {/source} </p> <------ accessing the php data in the html
... further html code
```

how could I achieve something like this so that its also easy for someone who is not a php-developer to create views with dynamic content and without creating a new module for every different view with dynamic content? Or do I just don't understand the principles of joomla and this can be done in some completely different (easier?) way?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use modules or plugins to insert dynamic content. But you only need to write one module or plugin, as both can use parameters.

Based on your description I guess the easiest way to achieve the result for you would be to

**a)** create a **content plugin** that replaces a custom code in your articles text; it should be something easy for you to parse, like

`[myservice:{year:2017, country:'uk'}]`

so your plugin  can test for the code easily, then retrieve the required parameters.

**b)** create a **editors-xtd plugin** for the editor to allow users to insert the code easily.  That will make it easy for the users to insert the data and possibly prevent most errors.

This  approach has the advantage of minimal coding (a plugin can be as simple as a single file, while with modules you'd have to write more files). Other than that, a module would work just as well using the `[loadposition]` shortcode. However, you would still need an editors-xtd plugin to help the users write the shortcode and pass in parameters.